# How do you reduce lighting when rendering? (See pictures to understand more)

Tags: lighting

[image]

The first picture is how it looks like when i render it, and the second picture is how I want it to look like when I render it. I don't know how to reduce the lighing, somebody help because I haven't used bender in a really long time.[image]

Comment: The shoes are illuminated the same, so you could just darken the materials. Also, check the color of your ambient light

Comment: If you are using Blender render decrease the specular intensity of the materials and increase the hardness.